# How can I force this z-index?

Tags: css, tooltip, z-index

On [euroworker.no/order](http://euroworker.no/order) (add something to the cart with Kjøp and Handlevogn).

I have a tooltip that shows the picture of the product when you hover the product name, for some reason it shows above the name, but under other elements, like lines and other product names.

The z-index has been set to the highest available for this part of the site, 999;. Nothing else has a higher index than this.

[JSFiddle of the tooltip code here](http://jsfiddle.net/HgWbe/12/).

And also how can I get the tooltip to appear in the middle? I tried `right:50%;` but guess that's not right.

Thanks.

Note: I am aware that I need to change some ID's to classes :)

Comment: Usually this occurs because of the drawing rules, whereby something drawn inside a parent will never 'overlap' it, as it only has permission to use the area inside the parent to draw itself.

Comment: Aha, of course. Is there any way to force this to overlap other elements?

Comment: I see several items with 999+ on the z-index...are you sure this isn't the problem?

Comment: Yes, they are totally unrelated.

Comment: @SLC: +1, that's a (perfectly reasonable) quirk I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I'm interested to know how to get around this. In a site I wrote once, I had to put the dropdown menu outside of any divs to allow the menu to drop down over the rest of my webpage. I have seen tools and widgets that have been able to get around this behaviour, and I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center it if you set:

```
width: 130px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -65px; /* since the half of 130 is 65*/
```

Background is a little longer:

Html:

```
<div id="JSwrap">

<div id="cart2Produkt">


<p>
    <a href="/Target-7050-Softphone-USB-Duo.220" target="_blank" class="tooltip" title="Target 7050 Softphone USB Duo ">

        <div class="back" ><img src="http://www.euroworker.no/public/upload/productimage/220-353-2.jpg?1251413379" alt="Target 7050 Softphone USB Duo " />
            <br />

        </div>

        Target 7050 Softphone USB Duo


    </a>
</p>

    <p>

    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#JSwrap{ /*for jsfiddle only*/
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:50px;
}

#cart2Produkt {
    /*z-index: 2000;*/
}

#cart2Produkt a.tooltip .back {
    z-index:999;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999px;
    opacity:0;
    padding:2px 3px;
    margin-left:8px;
    width:130px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

#cart2Produkt a.tooltip:hover .back{
    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    opacity:1;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    color:#6c6c6c;
    top:-35px;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:1px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;

}

#cart2Produkt img {
    z-index:999;
}
```

I tried it on your site and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, worked very well! Now to just findout if I can override this z-index issue.

Comment: I'm trying it at the website you provided, but I can't figure it out either.

Comment: Thanks, I just added `z-index:999;` to the parent, but no luck.

Comment: Ok, but it's now appearing behind the priduct name, also has broken in Chrome.

Comment: I thought you wanted it to appear behind the product name.

Comment: Ah, sorry if I gave off that impression, no the problem is that it is appearing behind other elemtents on the page. I need it to be topmost when activated (hovered). This broke in Chrome and still doesn't hover above other content.

Comment: Accepted as answered one and a half of this two part question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is a typo in your question, but a z-index is not set with pixels.  It should be:

```
z-index: 999;
```